# Why do we want to leave beta?

Tags: support

*Please ignore my inaptitude  - I couldn't find the information easily.*

What are the exact benefits for PuzzlingSE to finally graduate from beta state? 
(A new icon... and?)

Where do I best find that information?

Comment: Just as an FYI, there's quite a bit of activity on Meta Stack Exchange at the moment regarding changes in this topic, so an answer might change within the next few months.

Comment: [This MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) is one of the more recent additions to the discussion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple advantages to leaving beta:

- get a new logo
- get a new design
- hold elections for moderators as needed (one election cycle occurs during graduation, after which moderators pro tempore are replaced by elected moderators)
- get out of anonymity
- get the ability to migrate questions to other SE website (this might not be needed for puzzling.SE)
- get community ads on the website.

But there is also one big downside:

- the reputation threshold for most (if not all) privileges is raised.

  - see the current thresholds: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges
  - compare to the mother-ship threasholds: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges